# Connect not picking up variable changes

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to program an app which includes an animation. At the moment I want to start/stop the animation with a click on a button.
My solution includes two connects:

1. The first connect registers a click on the button and changes the value of the boolean `play`
2. The second connect links a timer to the animation step and every 200ms the step function is called and the scene is updated

Here is the piece of code:

```
bool play = false;

connect(button1, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [play]() mutable
    {
        qDebug() << "clicked!";
        play = !play;
        qDebug() << play;
    }
    );

connect(_timer, &QTimer::timeout, scene, [this, play, scene]()
    {
        if (play) {
            qDebug() << "play is true";
            step(mat);
            updateScene(mat, scene);
        }
    }
    );
```

Both connects seem to be working in the sense that if I click the button, I get the "clicked" message followed by the messages True/False interchanging with each click.
If I initialize `play` as true, the scene updates every 200ms as it should, however when `play` is false and I click the button, the second connect does not seem to pick up the change in the variable and the animation does not play. (Analogously, if I set `play as true and click the button, I get the clicked message but animation won't stop.)

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Have you ever tried write `&play` instead of `play` between lambda capture brackets?

Comment: Expanding on above comment, the default behaviour of lambda capture is to make a copy. in `play = !play;`, `bool play = false;`, and `if (play)`, all three `play`s are different variables.

Comment: That was the problem. Added the "&" and now the button starts and stops the animation. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider that in lambda body  only  a local name (variable) captured by reference(&) is allowed to be modified.
& before play means that it should be stored as reference, and if you don't put  & before play  means that it
should be stored as copy(implicitly will be captured by value).
by **default** lambda acts like const function, so that the lambda body
doesn’t modify the captured variables when the lambda declared **mutable** it means lambda isn't const any more and you can modify variables that they are captured by reference.